# XML RPC with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rpc

I am using XML-RPC from this GitHub
https://github.com/timheap/jquery-xmlrpc

However, when I try to run it now I do not get any response at all and no errors with FireBug.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.xmlrpc.js" type="javascript"></script>
<script>
            $.xmlrpc({
                url: 'http://mydomain.com:5060/RPC2',
                methodName: 'dispatcher.list',
                params: [],
                success: function(response, status, jqXHR) { },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { alert('fail:' + error); }
            });
</script>
```

If I surf to the adress above I get an xml document. Using Firebug I can see that there is a POST to http://mydomain.com:5060/RPC2 with the POST SOURCE `<methodCall><methodName>dispatcher.list</methodName><params/></methodCall>` but still no response.

Anyone have any ideas? How can I debug this further?

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you know there is no response ? The code you provide doesn't display the response.. `console.log(response)`

Comment: Ive checked in Firebug and the error: { ... } is called however none of the error parameters contain anything.

Comment: I'm guessing you're being blocked by the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: What is that? Am not sending a request to the same destination.